# Formatting Kubernetes logs as part of Github Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, github-flavored-markdown

I have one particular workflow that deploys a service and then if an error occurs, logs should be outputted. In a separate workflow file called `tests.yml`, I have the following:

```
name: TESTS
on: pull_request

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: View Logs
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: |
          kubectl -n dev logs dev/my-service
```

Is there any way I can improve the way logs are displayed on Github? Highlighting or any formatting action I can apply? They are quite dense and I am searching for a way in which I can make them more readble. Any help, documentation, example will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you